# Cronjobs do not run

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, jobs

I'm trying to run a cronjob to start and stop a server under a non-sudo user. I've tried asking others and doing what I saw from looking on google before asking here, but I'm still stuck.

Here's what's in my crontab for the `server` user:

```
* * * * * /home/server/startup/stop.sh
* * * * * /home/server/startup/start.sh
```

Here is what is in my `stop.sh` script:

```
#! /bin/sh
screen -r server -X quit
```

Everything runs normally if I run it using `sh`, and I only encounter a problem when using cron.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see there could be 2 possible problems:

1. If the lines you are running in crontab are (and only those):

   ```
   home/server/startup/stop.sh
   home/server/startup/start.sh
   ```

   then you are missing the time part of the line. If you want to run your program only once on boot you can run:

   ```
   @reboot home/server/startup/start.sh
   ```
2. You are not giving the full path to your program (possibly you are just missing a `/` in the begging). Try running

   ```
   * * * * * /home/server/startup/start.sh
   ```

   or

   ```
   @reboot /home/server/startup/start.sh
   ```

If these don't work I recommend you try the following to troubleshoot the issue:

- Run the command using `sh` in the cron:

  ```
   * * * * * /bin/sh /home/server/startup/start.sh
  ```
- Try redirecting the stdout and stderr of your command to a file and see if any errors occur

Comment: Hello, I edited my question to make it more clear about what I have. What does the@reboot do? is it needed?

Comment: The reboot runs your command only once when the device turns on

Comment: Oh ok, well I'm still stuck on my original question but thanks for helping.